# Online ticket booking using excel file to store user details instead of db using java

Tags: command, prompt, using

Hi could you please provide solution for how to register online ticket booking of user /new user and the register data should be save in excel file (ex userid colm1 seatno colm2) by dynamic way of user entering the value without creating fixed.

Comment: It sounds like you could just use Google forms for this, which would put the data in Google Sheets that you can export to Excel? But if you do need to build this yourself then I suggest you do set up a database and have that export to Excel. If it really does have to be Excel storage then you should probably set up a queue of some sort, put the new bookings in that and have a single worker process own the Excel file and read items from the queue to append to it.

Comment: And apologies I don't understand your requirement "by dynamic way of user entering the value without creating fixed."

Comment: Dynamic way is at runtime user needs to register the value instead of providing default values in the code.

Comment: That value needs to store in excel sheet